IntelliJ Commit Checks: How to accept ignored tests?
In IntelliJ, I like to enable the Run tests commit check. 
In my current project, I need to have some checks to be disabled on my M1 MacBook, but now IntelliJ complains every time, as the commit check failed, due to the ignored tests. 
How can I tell IntelliJ to accept ignored tests or change the run configuration to simply not run these tests?

you can follow these steps:1. Open IntelliJ and go to the "Settings" or "Preferences" window (usually located under the "File" menu).2. In the settings window, navigate to "Version Control" -> "Commit Dialog".3. In the "Commit Dialog" settings, locate the "Before commit" section.4. Look for the "Run tests" checkbox and deselect it. This will disable the "Run tests" commit check.Alternatively, if you want to exclude specific tests from running during commit checks

It's a known issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-57851
